# How to reference JS file variable to pyscript in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, web

I have the logic of a python code written. I want to integrate it to this website I made using HTML, CSS and JS. The website has a drag and drop box to input files. The URL of these files is generated in the variable called "fileURL" in the JS file. How do I use this file in fileURL to reference it in the python script i have integrated into pycharm via pyscript?

I tried simply running the python script without changing the file location but it showed "..no module found" error despite all the modules being installed. I  then added

```
        <py-config>
        packages = ['package_name']
         .....
        </py-config>
```

but can't move forward until i can get the user selected file in dragbox to my python code.

Comment: What module was it complaining about?  Pyscript has access to the page DOM exactly like Javascript, since the pyscript is actually being interpreted by Javascript code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.